Avro4s in Scala 3, create decoder for superclass
I guess this question is not strictly Avro4s-specific, but here is my problem: in the following scenario
trait Event
case class UserCreated(age: Int) extends Event
case class UserDeleted(age: Int) extends Event

I would like to be able to decode one such event based on an indication, something like
def getDecoderBasedOnType(eventName: String): Decoder[Event] = 
  eventName match {
    case "usercreated" => Decoder[UserCreated]
    case "userdeleted" => Decoder[UserDeleted]
  }

This won't work because the return type of this function is
def getDecoderBasedOnType(eventName: String): Decoder[_ >: UserCreated with UserDeleted <: Event]

Is there a way to achieve my goal? Pointers for me to understand what is happening are super welcome.

This question is not Scala 3 specific.
Nothing is wrong with the return type Decoder[_ >: UserCreated with UserDeleted <: Event], which is a legitimate existential type.
But if you really want Decoder[Event], the thing is that although Decoder could be covariant (trait Decoder[+T], i.e. Decoder[A] <: Decoder[B] for A <: B)
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Vj9pGvRiTMaFZIwJy8Z3EA
actually as defined it is invariant (i.e. Decoder[A], Decoder[B] are unrelated). But there is .map transforming Decoder[T] into Decoder[U]
trait Decoder[T] {
  self =>

  def decode(schema: Schema): Any => T

  final def map[U](f: T => U): Decoder[U] = new Decoder[U] {
    override def decode(schema: Schema): Any => U = { input =>
      f(self.decode(schema).apply(input))
    }
  }
}

https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s/blob/master/avro4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/avro4s/Decoder.scala#L21-L24
You can try
def getDecoderBasedOnType(eventName: String): Decoder[Event] = 
  eventName match {
    case "usercreated" => Decoder[UserCreated].map(identity)
    case "userdeleted" => Decoder[UserDeleted].map(identity)
  }

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/H5vMxWfBS8SN1FryfysFBg

Contravariance vs Covariance in Scala
How to check covariant and contravariant position of an element in the function?

This is incredible, thanks. What would you do if the .map method on Decoder wasn't available?

@ticofab First of all, not always Foo[Child] can be transformed into Foo[Parent]. I would follow semantics of Foo, whether it acts like a covariant type. If so I would define my own .map (maybe even with asInstanceOf). Otherwise I would be stuck with existentials.
